# OpenFileDialog limiting memory available

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory, openfiledialog, readfile

When executing the following code:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
string filename = "";
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
     filename = dialog.FileName;
     //create a new Thread and read the file.
}
else
{
     return;
}
```

I'm facing a strange memory behaviour: the memory usage goes up very fast till 710 MB, then it starts floatating byte-by-byte up and down close to 710MB, and finally I get a OutOfMemoryException.

But, if I run the code without the OpenFileDialog, by simply hard-coding the filepath:

```
string filename = "_complete_file_path_here";
//create a new Thread and read the file.
```

it will work without any problem: the memory goes up till 840 MB without esitations, and file get read correctly.

Any idea or feedback?

Comment: Have you tested on another computer to make sure it's not some 3rd-party application that has hooked into your Open File dialogs and is hosing them?

Comment: Yes, tried on three different laptops.

Comment: Looks all correct. Perhaps a bad question but, are you sure that the filename of the dialog is the same like the hard-coded filename?

Comment: Yes, same file.
Additionally, if I run the openfiledialog, but use hard-coded filepath, the problem will still happens.
Same: if I trigger the openfiledialog within a button click event, save the filepath, dispose the openfiledialog, set it to null, call the GC.Collect(), go take a coffee, and later on trigger the reading process using another button click event, I will still have memory problem.

Comment: It seems to me that this might be a case where the code snippet doesn't reflect the problem - there might be something going on in the actual code that is causing the problem, not shown here.  The code above, by itself, should not exhibit this problem.  Have you tried creating a brand-new project, with only the above code, and seeing if the problem occurs?

Comment: I think this is Microsoft's fault.  I bet VMware's reason for writing their own OpenFileDialog was that Win32's file dialog dll causes too much fragmentation in virtual memory.

Comment: @Dan: I could not really create a brand-new project, because the whole project is about reading that file and process it.

Comment: @Windows Programmer: so, you have any suggestion or workaround?

Comment: One suggestion is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825552/replacing-openfiledialog-savefiledialog-in-net but it's a commercial product.

Comment: @Dan: Additionally, I really think it's something related to memory, because when I try to load a smaller file, which does not exceed the 710 border-line, everything just works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of issue can be caused by a bad shell extension.  Use Process Explorer or the debugger output to check what DLLs are loaded into your process when you use the File Open dialog. If you find anything suspicious, try uninstalling the associated software. (Printers are for some reason often a culprit here).

The reason is that the file open dialog loads Windows Explorer shell extensions, and unfortunately many of the third-party ones are buggy.